# Get Rendered ( after JS + CSS ) html of webbrowser control output as text in c#

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I have following code

```
<html>
    <head>Test</head>
<body>
    <span style="display:none">Hidden Text</span>
    <span>Text To Display</span>
</body>
</html>
```

I want "Text To Display" as a output, i used following code

```
WebBrowser _browser = new WebBrowser();
_browser.DocumentText = htmlcode;           
Clipboard.Clear();
_browser.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", false, null);
_browser.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", false, null);            
string r = Clipboard.GetText();
```

but with no luck it. any body help me with out using any other library

thanks

Comment: Do you want to copy the result after the javascript/ajax are rendered?

Comment: i want the result we see on browser after javascript and css applied, in above case hidden text should not appear as output